# Adjust Image size to Textbox in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, text, alignment

I'm new to WordPress and I have looked for an answer on google and in here but had no luck. I have a two column area where in the left column there is some text and in the right there should be an image. The text area has a backgroundcolor which is alinged to the image. But when I now reduce the window width the image changes it size in height and width. Doing so after a short while the image is so small that the background color is visible and the text aree is not aligned to the image any more. I tried to find a widget whcih gives me the possibility to enter text (and maybe other widgets) on the one side and have a image on the other side. When the page is scaled the image should not change its size but should be cropped so it stil is aligned with the other area.

Has anybody a tip how to solve this? Any widget?

Best regards

Parascus